# Checkbox unchecked after refresh

Tags: javascript, checkbox, erb

I have checkboxes on my page, and the default value of all of them is true. However, the select_all checkbox became unchecked after a page refresh while the others remain checked.

```js
<script>
 var $checked = true;
 $('#select_all').click(function() {
  console.log('click select all button'+$checked)
  $checked = !$checked
  $(".activated").each(function(){
   $(this).prop("checked", $checked)
  });
 });
</script>
```

```html
<table cellspacing="10">
     <thead>
      <tr>
     <%= check_box_tag 'select_all', 1, true%>
     <%= label_tag :select_all, " Select All Doctors" %>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
     <th>Send Email</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
     <% @doctors.each do |doctor| %>
    <tr>
         <td><%= check_box_tag 'activated[]', doctor.id, true, class: 'activated'%></td>
     <td><%= doctor.first_name %></td>
     <td><%= doctor.last_name %></td>
     <td><%= doctor.email %></td>
    </tr>
     <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Here is a great tutorial for the same, http://www.webblogsforyou.com/check-or-uncheck-all-checkboxes-in-asp-net-gridview-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to save the boolean to toogle you can do the following:

```
<script>
    $('#select_all').change(function() {
      console.log('click select all button'+$checked)
      $checked = $(this).is(':checked')
      $(".activated").each(function(){
        $(this).prop("checked", $checked)
      });
    });
</script>
```

N.T Replaced click with change, its the approprate one to use with checkboxes.